# In sails js should we plug a mongoDB database calculating app into a POST Controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

The main interface app will return variables based on those initially POSTED by the client, and subsequent database calculations performed in real time by a dedicated engine.

In **Sails** can we plug the engine into a Controller used for returning the calculated variable?

What would be the best way to implement a real time link between the client and the engine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails comes with sockets support built in.  You can transmit the data out of your controller back to the client via sockets to keep everything in sync.

Reference this page for sockets in sails:
https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/6598661

As an aside, you could do everything using sockets, including the posting.

What is this 'dedicated engine'? Is this a separate service running somewhere else, or is it just logic for processing this data and handing it back to the controller?

If you want to put the data processing logic in the same app you can create a service which exports whatever data processing functions you need.  Then in your controller that is handling the POST requests you can call on those services as needed, process the data, and emit it back to the client.  All your sockets logic can go in that same controller since it is for communicating with the client interface.  I would consider just moving all of it to sockets.  If you look at the sails docs you will see that it has a similar interface with sockets where you can do standard CRUD operations: sockets.PUT, etc.

[Sails.js WebSockets](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it will be a processing app running on the server.  Do you mean posting within the same socket or... ?

Comment: Why don't you just include the processing in the same app?

Comment: If we include the processing in the same app what would be the fastest and most robust way to bind everything together within Sails ? Would there be one controller, several sockets...

Comment: You should be able to generate an api, and then just switch it over to sockets.

Comment: are you using angular on the front?

Answer (score 0):

No framework other than Sails, unless necessary for security purpose

Minimalist architecture implemented in Sails

- 1 POST API
- 1 POST Model
- 1 POST Controller
- 1 Socket per processing method
- 1 Socket switch within the Controller

Now if a secured framework integrates socket switching within controllers, that would come useful.

We may add middleware to the POST Model for the purpose of filtering text input data...